# When I use the YQL Console everything works fine, but when I use the REST API, the result is null

Tags: javascript, get, yql, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to use the `SELECT statement` in `YQL` in order to retrieve the data from some web pages. When I do so in the console [(as shown here in this link)](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?debug=true#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%20IN%20(%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-21%3Fid%3D72078%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-16%3Fid%3D72095%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-15%3Fid%3D72068%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-14%3Fid%3D71265%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-12%3Fid%3D71269%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-11%3Fid%3D70589%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-10%3Fid%3D72077%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-9%3Fid%3D70591%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-8%3Fid%3D69921%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-7%3Fid%3D70590%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-6%3Fid%3D70588%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-5%3Fid%3D70587%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-4%3Fid%3D68733%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-3%3Fid%3D68732%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-2%3Fid%3D68470%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fkisscartoon.me%2FCartoon%2FPAW-Patrol-Season-3%2FEpisode-1%3Fid%3D66850%22)) it works fine and does everything I want it to. However, when I use the `REST API RE`, I get this [image]

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I tried looking extensively online and turned up nothing.

Comment: Your secret code seems to be wrong.Just a guess...Did you read the error-message you provided?

Comment: it is needed use all those URL in a single request? try make separate requests.